# PSObject to ConvertTo-Html with header?

Tags: html, powershell

The following powershell script generates `*` as the column head. Why not `XXX`?

```
$a = "a","b","c"
$a | select -Property @{Name="XXX"; Expression={$_}} | ConvertTo-Html
```

How to make the column head to "XXX"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr> <!--- <------ * ----->
<tr><td>a</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This only seems to happen with single property objects and arrays. I tested this an got the same results. If I added another column of junk data it worked. The output is _similar_ even if you removed the call to `Select`. Other people have called this a [bug](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/588275ba-1b3a-42af-b59c-20264b25ff99/converttohtml-shows-in-html-table-column-header?forum=winserverpowershell) but im not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a known issue that was introduced in newer versions of powershell and never fixed:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/588275ba-1b3a-42af-b59c-20264b25ff99/converttohtml-shows-in-html-table-column-header?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else happens upon this as I did, this is what worked for me.

**Option One:**

```
$a = "a","b","c"
$a | ForEach-Object {$_ | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name XXX -Value $_; $_} | ConvertTo-Html -Property XXX
```

Which gives

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>XXX</th></tr>
<tr><td>a</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

**Option Two**

The other way, which may or may not work depending on whether the array is being built or is statically defined, is to build the array with objects.  If you're building the array yourself, using something like the following will also make generating the html file much simpler:

```
$a += New-Object PSObject -Property @{XXX=$value}
$a | ConvertTo-Html -Property XXX
```

Yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>XXX</th></tr>
<tr><td>a</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Not sure which works best for OP's 3 year old problem, but these both work in PSv2 and 3.  Hopefully someone finds some use from all this!